# Replicating `np.einsum` result via normal matrix operations

Tags: julia, numpy-einsum

I have implemented a TCB Spline in Python via Numpy. The critical piece of the code appears below:

```
np.einsum('km,km,kl,lm->m',xdiffpow_knot, h_pow_knot[:,i], hermite_matrix, lag_knot[:,i])
```

where `k` and `l` are always 4 (`k` being powers of 0 to 3 and `l` being the 4 control points used by TCB splines) and `m` is the length of the array `x` I want to interpolate.

I implemented via `np.einsum` at the time as I couldn't figure out the necessary matrix operations to do it without `np.einsum`. It seems as though I'm left with an extra `m` in the result (note that the first two `km` terms are simply element-wise multiplication).

Now I'm reimplementing in Julia without `einsum` (so I can take advantage of algorithmic differentiation in `ForwardDiff`, `ReverseDiff`, etc.). How do I replicate the above einsum via matrix operations?

**What have I tried?**

Thinking solely about the dimensions involved and making the dot-product work, it feels as though I'm missing an `m`-element vector. The only `m` element vector that makes sense is a 1-s vector, which I believe would act as a summation. But I'd like to validate that this is correct in theory before I rely on it.

**Full Code. It's Ugly...**

```
HERMITE_MATRIX = np.array([[ 2.,-2., 1., 1.],
                           [-3., 3.,-2.,-1.],
                           [ 0., 0., 1., 0.],
                           [ 1., 0., 0., 0.]])


def hermite(x_knot, y_knot, tension=0.0, continuity=0.0, bias=0.0, weight_fwd_knot=None, hermite_matrix=HERMITE_MATRIX):
    order = 3
    h_knot = np.diff(x_knot)
    h_pow_knot = (1.0 / h_knot) ** np.arange(order, -1, -1)[:,None]
    is_first_knot = np.isclose(x_knot, x_knot[0])
    is_last_knot = np.isclose(x_knot, x_knot[-1])
    y_next_knot = np.roll(y_knot,-1)
    y_prev_knot = np.roll(y_knot, 1)
    x_next_knot = np.roll(x_knot,-1)
    x_prev_knot = np.roll(x_knot, 1)
    if weight_fwd_knot is None:
        weight_fwd_knot = np.where(is_last_knot, 0.0, np.where(is_first_knot, 1.0, (x_next_knot - x_knot)/(x_next_knot - x_prev_knot)))
    weight_bak_knot = 1.0 - weight_fwd_knot
    dydxfwd_knot = np.where(is_last_knot, (y_knot - y_prev_knot)/(x_knot - x_prev_knot), (y_next_knot - y_knot)/(x_next_knot - x_knot))
    dydxbak_knot = np.where(is_first_knot, (y_next_knot - y_knot)/(x_next_knot - x_knot), (y_knot - y_prev_knot)/(x_knot - x_prev_knot))
    dy_in_knot = (1 - tension) * ((1 + continuity) * (1 - bias) * dydxfwd_knot * weight_fwd_knot + (1 - continuity) * (1 + bias) * dydxbak_knot * weight_bak_knot)
    dy_out_knot = (1 - tension) * ((1 - continuity) * (1 - bias) * dydxfwd_knot * weight_fwd_knot + (1 + continuity) * (1 + bias) * dydxbak_knot * weight_bak_knot)
    lag_knot = np.array([y_knot[:-1], y_next_knot[:-1], dy_out_knot[:-1] * h_knot, dy_in_knot[1:] * h_knot])
    def f(x):
        i = np.maximum(np.minimum(np.searchsorted(x_knot, x, side="right") - 1, x_knot.size - 2), 0)
        xdiffpow_knot = (x - x_knot[i]) ** np.arange(order, -1, -1)[:,None]
        return np.einsum('km,km,kl,lm->m',xdiffpow_knot, h_pow_knot[:,i], hermite_matrix, lag_knot[:,i])
    return f
```

Comment: I think [OMEinsum.jl](https://github.com/under-Peter/OMEinsum.jl) does provide exactly what you're looking for. But isn't the function non-differentiable mainly because you call maximum, minimum, and searchsorted?

Comment: Generally there's no need to differentiate across the `x` arrays, which are the ones that impact or are impacted by the non-differentiable functions. It is almost always the case that the jacobian is something like `dyknotdy`. Thus far I've implemented a linear, cubic, and exponential tension spline in Julia and all `dyknotdy` seem to work as expected.

Comment: Sorry, flip that. `dydyknot` is the jacobian.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> np.einsum('km,km,kl,lm->m',a,a,a,a)
array([142, 392])
```

This can be computed using basic linear algebra operations.
Observe the 'kl,lm' part is traditional matrix multiplication and can be sub-computed to yield 'km':

```
>>> x = np.matmul(a,a)
```

Now the remaining 'km,km,km->m' is element wise multiplication and summing over index 'k'

```
>>> y = a * a * x
>>> y
array([[  7,  40],
       [135, 352]])

>>> np.sum(y, axis=0)
array([142, 392])
```